# What exactly is carried over into the Epilogue?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I'm just about to finish Chapter 6, and was wondering what the best way to prepare for the Epilogue is. I understand that you lose

> your money and horse

but what about anything else? Different online sources say different things, and the official guide is useless in this area.

So what do you get to keep?

- Clothing
- Outfits
- Weapons
- Ammo
- Satchels
- Saddles

From inside your satchel:

- Provisions
- Tonics
- Ingredients
- Materials
- Kit
- Valuables
- Documents

Which of the above carry over?

Answer (score 3):

You get to keep everything except your horse and money, but you won't have access to your full array of stuff straight away in the epilogue.

If your horse is the white Arabian stallion from up north, which IIRC is the best horse, that respawns anyway.

Make a manual save just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you lose any perishables and consumables that is

- tonics
- food and horse provisions
- animal parts and plants (except those needed for the *Duchesses and other Animals* quest)
- gun oil, pomade,..

Furthermore, you lose all money and the horses.
Most valuables are also lost, which seems to be a recent change. This includes gold bars and any stuff found on enemies. Also special valuables are lost (e.g. the viking comb is gone)

You do get to keep

- experience drinks like Pirate Rum and Valerian Root.
- guns and ammunition
- cigarette cards
- wearables (clothing, outfits, equipment, saddles)
- documents

Had I known about this, I'd have rushed with Arthur, instead of exploring with him, given that nearly everthing you find is gone forever.